# Servicebustrigger deserialization fails

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

I have a simple webjob that use servicebus:

```
   public async Task ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("asset-updates-in")] BrokeredMessage message,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Running job");
        log.LogInformation("GotMessage"+ message.ContentType);
```

Message is sent by Biztalk team, has a mime type 'text/xml'
And looks like this:

```
 <gip:GetDeviceUpdateResult xmlns:gip="http://schemas.ores.net/customer/breakdown-manager/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <gip:Event>
        <gip:Id>5886</gip:Id>
        <gip:Action>Upsert</gip:Action>
        <gip:Timestamp>2019-09-20T13:35:40</gip:Timestamp>
      </gip:Event>
      <gip:Cabin>
        <gip:Id>5001874</gip:Id>
        <gip:BusinessId>029843</gip:BusinessId>
        <gip:Name>RUE DE LANDEN TEST 2</gip:Name>
        <gip:DistrictId>1590</gip:DistrictId>
      </gip:Cabin>
    </gip:GetDeviceUpdateResult>
```

As soon as my webjob gets the message i have this error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception
>   while executing function: UpdateFunctions.ProcessQueueMessage --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Exception binding parameter
>   'message' ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Binding parameters to
>   complex objects (such as 'BrokeredMessage') uses Json.NET
>   serialization or XML object serialization.
>
> 1. If ContentType is 'application/json' deserialize as JSON
> 2. If ContentType is not 'application/json' attempt to deserialize using Message.GetBody, which will handle cases like XML object
>      serialization
> 3. If this deserialization fails, do a final attempt at JSON deserialization to catch cases where the content type might be
>      incorrect
>
> The JSON parser failed: Unexpected character encountered while parsing
>   value: ?. Path '', line 0, position 0.

So it seems to using json parser while data is xml fromat...

If I change my webjob like this:

```
 public async Task ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("asset-updates-in")] string message,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Running job");
        log.LogInformation("GotMessage"+ message);
```

I get :

```
[09/20/2019 11:38:43 > da4c4f: INFO]       GotMessage<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><gip:GetDeviceUpdateResult xmlns:gip="http://schemas.ores.net/customer/breakdown-manager/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><gip:Event><gip:Id>5889</gip:Id><gip:Action>Upsert</gip:Action><gip:Timestamp>2019-09-20T13:38:11</gip:Timestamp></gip:Event><gip:Cabin><gip:Id>5001874</gip:Id><gip:BusinessId>029843</gip:BusinessId><gip:Name>RUE DE LANDEN</gip:Name><gip:DistrictId>1590</gip:DistrictId></gip:Cabin></gip:GetDeviceUpdateResult>
[09/20/2019 11:38:43 > da4c4f: INFO] info: Function.ProcessQueueMessage[0]
```

I guess I could deserialize myself, but it stinks a bit... I am missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `BrokeredMessage` class is deprecated in the webjob 3.x.
WebJobs SDK version 3.x is using the new .NET Standard service bus client (`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` with [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message) class).

So you could use this to deserialize it.

```
public static void processservicebus(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]Message message,
        ILogger log)
        {

            log.LogInformation(message.ContentType);

            XDocument orderOut = XDocument.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));

        }
```

[image]